# Disable automatic line numbering for MDPI_template

Tags: line-numbering, mdpi

I'm writing a study in MDPI (Multidisciplinary Digital Publishing Institute) template, as the following image shows, this template automatically generates line numbering and I want to disable it.

[image: TEMPLATE]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class `mdpi` has two options to choose the status of the document : `submit` (default) and `accept`. When you choose `submit`, line numbers are enable. If you choose `accept`, line numbers are disable but you will have an error about a missing file (the logo of the journal). A workaround is to add `\preto{\abstractkeywords}{\nolinenumbers}` to the preamble of your document.

Comment: Thank you! I had tryed to changed the submit for accept and got the error. Using \preto{\abstract keywords}{\nolin numbers} works.

Comment: @MelanieGissel, you should accept the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: Hi \preto{\abstract{One of the }}}{\nolinenumbers}, and choose accept option. But there is an error, could you tell me in detail, how to change it

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't want line numbers, the simplest method is to disable them altogether:

```
\documentclass[journal,article,submit,moreauthors,pdftex]{Definitions/mdpi}

\renewcommand{\linenumbers}{}
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be something wrong with the font used in the answer provided by MelanieGissel.

This is what worked for me. In the line preceding the command \abstract, insert a line with the following:

\preto{\abstractkeywords}{\nolinenumbers}

Then run Latex.

Answer (score 0):

On 14th December 2020, MDPI has updated its LaTeX template. This command

**\preto{\abstractkeywords}{\nolinenumbers}**

is not working. In the new template, the page number starts after the template line

**\end{paracol}
\nointerlineskip**